# SQL Query Sorting Rows into Columns

Tags: sql

I am new SQL and I am trying to find a solution how I can turn the following table data into a new structure.

Table Fields

Before

```
| Plots.   | Task.    | Cost
| -------- | -------- |———————
| Plot 1   | Lift 1   | 230.00
| Plot 1   | Lift 2   | 300.00
| Plot 2   | Lift 1   | 400.00
| Plot 2   | Lift 2   | 345.00
| Plot 3   | Lift 1   | 445.78
| Plot 3   | Lift 2   | 555.00
```

After

```
| Plots    | Lift 1   | Lift 2
| -------- | -------- |———————
| Plot 1   | 230.00   | 300.00
| Plot 2   | 400.00   | 345.00
| Plot 3   | 445.78   | 555.00
```

The data is shown above

Comment: Look for `PIVOT` support of your DB.

Comment: The SQL language has a very strict rule that you MUST know about your result columns at query compile time, **before looking at any data**, even with a (hint) `PIVOT`. If you can't determine how many `Lift` columns you need, you won't be able to do this as a single query. Instead, you'll need a 3 step process to load data about your needed columns, build a new SQL string based on that data dynamically, and then run the final string. Even if you do know about your columns, this kind of pivot is often better handled in the reporting tool or client code in the first place.

Comment: For the Task column, do you have only two values (Lift 1, Lift 2)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your DBMS but the following will work in SQL Server. YMMV in other DBMS products:

This assumes you only have the two values Lift 1 and Lift 2, something more dynamic might be required otherwise

```
SELECT  Plots,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Task = 'Lift 1' THEN Cost END) AS Lift1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Task = 'Lift 2' THEN Cost END) AS Lift2
FROM    MyData
GROUP BY Plots
```

alternatively, you can use the (less readable IMO) PIVOT variant:

```
SELECT  Plots,
        [Lift 1],
        [Lift 2]
FROM    MyData
PIVOT (
        MAX(Cost)
        FOR Task IN ([Lift 1],[Lift 2])
) AS pt
```